# Law of large numbers weak vs strong

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Does someone have an example where the strong law of large numbers do not hold, but the weak law do hold ?

If you think there is no such example, please explain why there are 2 laws of large numbers with different conditions if the strong law derives the weak completely.

Comment: There are some cases where the strong law holds but not the weak law. You can only say if the assumptions of weak law hold, then the strong law derives the weak law

Comment: Three examples [at the obvious place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Differences_between_the_weak_law_and_the_strong_law).

Comment: It's the strong law who do not hold , and I would like an explanation please.

Comment: @Itai When the weak law holds, the strong law always holds

Comment: @Liu Gang, actually it is opposite. Strong law implies weak law. Convergence almost surely (strong law) is stronger than convergence in probability ( weak law) A good explanation of this can be found even on Wikipedia.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner I mean the assumptions in the statement of weak law are stronger than the assumptions in the statement of strong law, so when weak laws holds, the strong law holds. The weak law is a theorem, it's different from the definition of convergence in probability

Comment: @Liu Gang Again you are wrong .

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner There is no doubt that convergence almost surely implies convergence in probability. But what I am saying is that in the statement of weak law, we assume the variance is finite, it implies the absolute first moment is finite, which is the assumption of strong law. If you still think I am wrong, please give some arguments, thank you!

Comment: @Liu Gang, it does not matter under what condition you can or cannot prove weak or strong law. The fact is that the strong law convergence ALWAYS implies the weak law convergence, so you cannot have an example when strong law holds and weak law does not, while the opposite examples do exist. My great apology if I am wrong but I am almost sure :) that I am correct.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner I think we are using different definitions. For you, the laws are their conclusions, for me, they are their assumptions and conclusions. At least we both agree that convergence almost surely implies convergence in probability

Comment: @Liu Gang, assumptions for strong law are stronger than for weak law, because under these assumptions weak law holds too.

Comment: Does the number the weak law said it converge to in probability is considered the expectation or not ?

Comment: is the expected value in 1,2 examples really considered expected value or not ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Differences_between_the_weak_law_and_the_strong_law

Comment: I always found the notes by Terry Tao on this subject, crisp, clean and clear. Take a look. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/the-strong-law-of-large-numbers/

Answer (score 0):

Let be $X_2,X_3,\cdots$ random independent variables, such that
$$\mathbb{P}(X_n=n)=\mathbb{P}(X_n=-n)=\dfrac{1}{2n\log n},~\mathbb{P}(X_n=0)=1-\dfrac{1}{n\log n}$$